# Gradle - Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact

Tags: android, gradle, tensorflow-lite

I've the following line in my gradle android project inside the module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 // a lot of dependencies
 implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

and it causes the gradle build to fail with the following error

```
Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT:20210331.060351-75, variantName=null, artifactFile=C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.tensorflow\tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops\0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT\b03a88bda4ad93e6fefe285f9ea303d28433eacc\tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops-0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={__current_build__=C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Myapp2}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@5c4450a)
```

I had the same implementation in a diffrent project and it worked but in this project this error keep on appearing.

what causes this error? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got the same error when I was adding `aar`. I changed the `implementation path` and then fixed.

old path

`implementation files('libs/test.aar')`

new path

`implementation files('../libs/test.aar')`

Comment: How implementation path can be changed?

Comment: I am getting same error even after changing the path

Comment: for me was the other way around ... "old path" is the new and the "new path" was the way I had it and was throwing an error.

Comment: And if you are adding the dependency to a module, new path would be more like `implementation files('../modulenamehere/libs/test/aar')`

Answer (score 33):

In my case I had to increase amount of RAM to 4096 in `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
```

After that project synced correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I got the error when I was adding unit-ads.aar . I changed this in my code and its works for me.

Old Code

```
implementation files('../libs/unity-ads.aar')
```

New Code

```
implementation files('libs/unity-ads.aar')
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to go to the equivalent folder:

> C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.tensorflow\tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops

And delete it, then try to sync again, and worked.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the path well for example:

```
implementation(files("./src/libs/myfile.aar"))
```

or

```
implementation files("./src/libs/myfile.aar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can be more explicit like this.

```
implementation files("$rootProject.projectDir/libs/test.aar")
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing **arr/jar** to AS, I have encountered this issue.
My method is switching **Project** view to **Project** mode (not **Android** mode) and after that add **aar/jar** to **libs** folder (or any folder)

[image: dotrinh]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an Artifact error was generated After Project migrated from Android to AndroidX

Error was

```
Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0, variantName=null, artifactFile=/home/mittal/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.0/4266e2118d565daa20212d1726e11f41e1a4d0ca/activity-1.8.0.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={__current_build__=/home/mittal/StudioProjects/android/android-sdk}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@6fbb61c0)
```

Excluding Activity library from material dependencies solved the error

```
    implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.activity', module: 'activity'
}
```

So if you are facing the artifact error then check the library mentioned in the error and Try removing that library may help you.